# combobox value in spring and thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, combobox, thymeleaf

I need to get a value from a combobox but i keep getting the error: 'Required String parameter 'productid' is not present'

This is he html code from the form:

```
<body th:object="${picture}">
<form method="post" multiple="true">
  Authhor: <label th:text="*{ownerName}"/><br/>
  Title: <label th:text="*{name}"/><br/>
  Description: <label th:text="*{description}"/><br/>
  Price: €<label th:text="*{price}"/><br/>
  Product:
  <select th:field="${productss}" th:remove="all-but-first" name="productid">
    <option th:each="product : ${productss}" th:value="${product.id}"
            th:text="${product.name + '   (+ €' + product.price + ')'}">
      Productname
    </option>
  </select><br/>
  <img width="250" heigth="250" th:src="*{plainURL}"/><br/>
  <button align="right" class="btn" type="submit" name="add">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check">Add to shopping cart</span>
  </button><br/>
</form>
</body>
```

and this is the method in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = IMAGE_ID, method = RequestMethod.POST, params = {"add"})
public String add(@PathVariable("id") int id, HttpSession session, Model model,
                  @RequestParam(required = true, name = "productid") String productid) {

    System.out.println("product id = " + productid);
    items = (List<ShoppingCartItem>) session.getAttribute("shoppingcart");
    if (items == null) {
        // create new shopping cart if no cart exists and add an example item
        items = new ArrayList();
    }
    Picture p = DatabaseManager.getItem(Picture.class, 5);

    Product pr = new Product();
    pr.setName("Download");
    pr.setPrice(9.99);

    double totalprice = Math.round(p.getPrice() + pr.getPrice() * 100.0) / 100.0;
    ShoppingCartItem item = new ShoppingCartItem(id,
            "https://d2u6gqtb2vk2pn.cloudfront.net/images_(5).jpg",
            p.getDescription(), pr.getName(), 1, totalprice);
    items.add(item);

    // add shopping cart to session
    session.setAttribute("shoppingcart", items);

    return "redirect:/cart";
}
```

I can't see what I am doing wrong, but I can't get the selected value from the combobox in the controller.